# Getting a combination of numbers where each digit is lower than a certain number

Tags: python

Given length `k` and `target` and `limit`, I want to get a combination of numbers where each digit contains `[0 ~ limit]` and can have `k` numbers and sums up to `target`.

So, for example, if I have `k=2` `target=4` and `limit=4`,

I will have

```
[0, 4], [1, 3], [2, 2], [3, 1], [4, 0]

def get_combination(spots, target):
    if spots == 1:
        yield (target, )
    else:
        for i in range(target + 1):
            for j in get_combination(spots - 1, target - i):
                yield (i, ) + j
```

I've tried the method above, but this one has no limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there! You can make a very simple modification to account for the limit.

```
def get_combination(spots, target, limit):
    if spots == 1 and target <= limit:
        yield (target, )
    elif spots > 1:
        for i in range(limit + 1):
            for j in get_combination(spots - 1, target - i, limit):
                yield (i, ) + j
```

When we get to the base case of `spots == 1`, we want to make sure the remainder is less than the limit. If it isn't, don't yield anything. And then when we're choosing numbers to go into the combination, don't choose anything over the limit!

```
>>> list(get_combination(2,4,3))
[(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I also want to include 0 in the digits?

Comment: 0 is already included - it's not in my example because the limit is 3, which means that 0 would be paired with 4 (over the limit).

Comment: Another heads up: you might want to make sure the target is greater than zero as well - having a large number of spots would mean that some elements will be less than zero!

Comment: Is there a way to exclude negative numbers from the result?

Comment: You can do it in a similar fashion - simply check the target and only yield it if it's greater than or equal to zero

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `limit` to your existing function like this:

```
def get_combination(spots, target, limit):
    if spots != 1:
        for i in range(limit + 1):
            for j in get_combination(spots - 1, target - i, limit):
                yield (i, ) + j
    elif 0 <= target <= limit:
        yield (target,)
```

so that:

```
print(list(get_combination(3, 8, 4)))
```

would output:

`[(0, 4, 4), (1, 3, 4), (1, 4, 3), (2, 2, 4), (2, 3, 3), (2, 4, 2), (3, 1, 4), (3, 2, 3), (3, 3, 2), (3, 4, 1), (4, 0, 4), (4, 1, 3), (4, 2, 2), (4, 3, 1), (4, 4, 0)]`

Comment: Is there a way to exclude negative numbers from the result?